# I want to pass Marker component to GoogleMapReact children

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

Typescript and react are used.
Markers are displayed at the clicked position using google-map-react.
The following error occurs when passing a Marker component to GoogleMapReact with children.
Please let me know if you know how to solve this problem.

error

> (alias) class GoogleMapReact (alias) namespace GoogleMapReact import
> GoogleMapReact No overloads match this call.   Overload 1 of 2,
> '(props: Props | Readonly): googleMapReact', caused the
> following error
> type '{ children: Element; bootstrapURLKeys: { key: string; }; defaultCenter: { lat: number; lng: number; }; defaultZoom: number;
> onClick: (e: ClickEventValue) => void; }' cannot be assigned to types
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly'.
> Property 'children' does not exist for type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.
> Overloading 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): googleMapReact',
> caused the following error
> type '{ children: Element; bootstrapURLKeys: { key: string; }; defaultCenter: { lat: number; lng: number; }; defaultZoom: number;
> onClick: (e: ClickEventValue) => void; }' cannot be assigned to types
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly'.
> Property 'children' does not exist for type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly'.

```
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
export const Area = () => {
  const defaultLatLng = {
    lat: 10.99835602,
    lng: 77.01502627,
  },
return (
  <Box height="340px">
   <GoogleMapReact
    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: Key }}
    defaultCenter={defaultLatLng}
    defaultZoom={10}
   >
    <Maker lat={59.955413} lng={30.337844} />
   </GoogleMapReact>
  </Box>
 )
}

interface SubProps {
  lat: number;
  lng: number;
}
const Maker: FunctionComponent<SubProps> = () => <img src="location.svg"} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably has something to do with your dependencies.

My code is similar to yours:

```js
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        center={center}
        zoom={zoom}
        draggable={draggable}
        onChange={onChange}
        onChildMouseDown={onMarkerInteraction}
        onChildMouseUp={onMarkerInteractionMouseUp}
        onChildMouseMove={onMarkerInteraction}
        onChildClick={onStoreMarkerClick}
        onClick={onClick}
        bootstrapURLKeys={{
          key: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY!,
          libraries: ["places", "geometry"],
        }}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
        onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }) => apiHasLoaded(map, maps)}
      >
        <GoogleMapCenterMarker />

        {storeLocations.map((storeLocation) => (
          <GoogleMapStoreMarker
            key={storeLocation.uniqueStoreName}
            lat={storeLocation.storeLocationLatitude}
            lng={storeLocation.storeLocationLongitude}
            store={storeLocation}
          />
        ))}
      </GoogleMapReact>

      <div className="mt-4">
        <div className="text-center">
          {" "}
          Latitude: <span>{lat}</span>, Longitude: <span>{lng}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="text-center">
          {" "}
          Zoom: <span>{zoom}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="text-center">
          {" "}
          Address: <span>{address}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Here is my list of google map related dependencies:

```
├─ @googlemaps/js-api-loader@1.13.7
├─ @types/google-map-react@2.1.5
├─ @types/google.maps@3.48.1
├─ google-map-react@2.1.10
│  ├─ @googlemaps/js-api-loader@^1.7.0
│  ├─ workbox-google-analytics@6.5.2
├─ workbox-google-analytics@6.5.2
```